# 32 and 64 bit ASP.NET deployments

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

Is the ASP.NET/C# code I develop inherently 32/64 bit agnostic, because it's compiled to some sort of intermediate language? The reason I ask is that I compile my ASP.NET app on an x64 laptop and then deploy on an x32 server. There are no problems. Further, I see no options for selecting between a 32 and 64 bit build in VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your code to

- AnyCPU - executed in 32bit on a 32bit runtime and 64bit on a 64bit runtime
- x86 - forced to execute in 32bit
- x64 - forced to execute in 64bit (will not work on 32bit OS)
- (IA64 - Itanumim)

If you compile for AnyCPU you are in good shape, and more often than not, you will use the AnyCPU platform target. (Build -> Configuration Manager in Visual Studio)

When compiling .Net code it's compiled into Intermediate Language code (MSIL) which in turn is compiled to native code at runtime by the .Net framework/runtime.

Comment: The way I assume it works is if you choose a more specific CPU then you get some CPU specific optimizations. Either that, or it's so you don't crash and burn when P/Invoking

Comment: I think it is mostly due to p/invoke. But there are reasons to want to run 32bit on a 64bit system. Specially high load apps with a lot of mem usage, but below the barrier for wanting 64bit mem addressing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some 3rd party libraries that can only run as x86.

The best approach would be to have your local environment (local IIS) to match the settings of your target webserver as much as possible. So if your target IIS only runs as 32 bit, set the "force 32 bit" property of the applicationpool on your local IIS to true.